# How to use the hmmsearch on prototypic repetitive sequences Repbase Update database?

Tags: fasta, hidden-markov-models

I want to use the hmmsearch proposed in [*Convergence of retrotransposons in
oomycetes and plants*](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5348765/) by Kirill Ustyantsev, Alexandr Blinov and Georgy Smyshlyaev. After the help from [terdon](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/a/3037/48) I managed to create the correct profile I assumed that the command

```
hmmsearch aRNH_profile.hmm prirep.ref > output.out
```

would be the correct command. I downloaded the compressed database `RepBase22.11.fasta.tar.gz` from [here](http://www.girinst.org/server/RepBase/index.php) in the fasta format. 
However when unpacking I get the following tree

```
.
├── angrep.ref
├── appendix
│   ├── angapp.ref
│   ├── athapp.ref
│   ├── bctapp.ref
│   ├── cbrapp.ref
│  ....
├── athrep.ref
├── bctrep.ref
├── cbrrep.ref
...
```

which file is the correct fasta file? I assumed `prirep.ref`  might be correct file but the output shows

```
[No hits detected that satisfy reporting thresholds]
```

Comment: The site requires an account in order to download. Isn't there a README or similar file explaining what each file contains? What other files are there?
 Are they all `.ref`?

Comment: true. I created a account. All the files are .ref files and there is no README file

Comment: OK, so what species are you looking for? All plants? Plants and fungi? Only fungi? How about algae? What is the "correct" file for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RepBase explain what these files are on [their website](http://www.girinst.org/repbase/update/index.html). It is usually a good idea to check the documentation when downloading files so you know what you're downloading.

Based on the list of files described on the linked page, there is no `prirep.ref` file, so I assume you mean `plnrep.ref` which is "Other Plants". In any case, again according to that page, the files with plant and/or fungal data (which is what I assume you want; you never said) are:

athrep.ref  Arabidopsis thaliana
oryrep.ref  Oryza sativa
dcotrep.ref Other Dicot Plants
mcotrep.ref Other Monocot Plants
grasrep.ref Other Grass Plants
plnrep.ref  Other Plants
fngrep.ref  Fungi

There's also `chlrep.ref` for the green alga *Chlamydomonas reinhardtii*, and `diarep.ref` for the diatom *Thalassiosira pseudonana*. I don't know whether you would want to consider either here.

In any case, since these are fasta files, you cna combine them by simply `cat`ing them together:

```
cat athrep.ref oryrep.ref dcotrep.ref mcotrep.ref grasrep.ref \
    plnrep.ref fngrep.ref > plantsAndFungi.ref
```

The, run your search on the `plantsAndFungi.ref` file.

Comment: as I was talking to the author he mentioned that they concatenated all the files and ran a translator on nucleotide on the data. Before running the search